# Redirect input from code or terminal to running code or terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, bash-scripting

Currently, I am using a software script that requires continuous input through the terminal. The script evaluates files continuously by receiving **path input** and evaluating the file in the path.

**The goal**: Is it possible to run a script requiring input through passing input from **another terminal** or script.

The evaluation software loads a lot of data before being ready for processing, that is why I would prefer to keep the software running and simply pass input from time to time. Instead of starting up the software and load all data required (which takes time).

I can mention that I have tried **tty** to find: 
`$ /dev/pts/19` 
then through other terminal run:
`$ <command> <myinput> > /dev/pts/19` 
where command is replaced with 'echo / print' 
However, it just prints in the other terminal, it does not act as input to the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a named pipe:

```
mkfifo pipe
```

Make sure it won't close (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366278/108618)):

```
exec 3<>pipe
```

Feed your script from the pipe:

```
<pipe your_script.sh
# or if you want to see incoming data
<pipe tee >(your_script.sh)
```

Then from another terminal use `echo`, `printf` or whatever:

```
echo "/some/path/or/another/input" > pipe
```

or

```
cat large_input.txt > pipe
```

or

```
script_that_generates_input.sh > pipe
```

But beware of race condition! Don't feed the pipe from two or more sources at the same time; always wait for the current feeding command to exit before you run the next. Note if one source passes a lot of data, it may be held midway, until the receiving side processes the data. Put `mbuffer` (with arguments that fit your usage case) before `your_script.sh` to create a buffer that can store more incoming data before any feeding command is put on hold.